# Resolve: "Internal error executing the custom function" while getting value from Url

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a custom function that gets value from [YahooFinance](https://finance.yahoo.com/) using [Cheerio](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs). It runs fine when I run it from the script editor. However, when I call it in Google sheet cell it shows the following error:

> Error: Internal error executing the custom function.

It was running fine before today. I tried to refresh the sheet and formulas but it did not work out. **Here is how this looks**:

[image: Error]

**Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.**